# Oracle join tables and always include all possible results

Tags: oracle, join

I am trying to join two tables that look like the following:

```
Table 1

Letter | Value
   A       2
   B       5


Table 2

Letter | Number
   A       1
   C       7
```

I am trying to join these tables so that, regardless of what is in the tables at the time, there will always be an A,B,C record in the result. In other words, this would be displayed:

```
Letter | Value | Number
   A       2       1
   B       5      null
   C      null     7
```

The three letter records should always be displayed regardless of if they are in the tables. So assume table2 looks like this:

```
Letter | Number
   A       1
```

Then I want the following results even though there is now no 'C' record:

```
Letter | Value | Number
   A       2       1
   B       5      null
   C      null    null
```

Could anyone show how to do this?

Comment: What's the source of your letters?  Another table, or just 3 constant values?

Comment: Besides the last case this is a typical left outer join example. For the last case the best thing to do is to join it with a table which always contains all possible values `select a.letter, b.value, c.number from a,b,c where a.letter = b.letter and a.letter = c.letter`

Comment: @LoztInSpace They are values within tabl1 and table2. There is no 'letters' table that contains all possible letter values.

Comment: You need a letters table that contains all possible values. If B _never_ appears in any other table, you need a master table to tell it that should be included regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `SELECT ... FROM DUAL` with a `CONNECT BY` clause to generate a stable set of letters in case some letters don't appear in either table.

```
with base_set_of_letters as (
  select chr(rownum + 64) as Letter -- ascii 65=A, 66=B, 67=C, ...
  from dual
  connect by rownum <= 3) -- increase this number if you want more letters
select l.letter, t1.value, t2.xNumber
  from base_set_of_letters l
  left join Table1 t1 on t1.letter = l.letter
  left join Table2 t2 on t2.letter = l.letter
order by l.letter;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb119/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you were just looking to get all rows that existed joined, irregardless of whether data existed on both sides of the relationship, you'd be looking for a FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.LETTER, t2.LETTER) AS LETTER,
       t1.VALUE,
       t2.NUM
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
  FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 t2
    ON t2.LETTER = t1.LETTER
  ORDER BY COALESCE(t1.LETTER, t2.LETTER);
```

which produces

```
LETTER  VALUE   NUM
A       2       1
B       5       (null)
C       (null)  7
```

But this would only give you rows where you've got a key value ('A', 'B', or 'C') - however, if one is missing you'd get nothing. IMO you need a third table, perhaps called ALPHABET, containing all possible letters:

```
CREATE TABLE ALPHABET (LETTER  CHAR(1));
```

and populated with 'A', 'B', 'C', etc. In this case your join would become:

```
SELECT a.LETTER,
       t1.VALUE,
       t2.NUM
  FROM ALPHABET a
  FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_1 t1
    ON t1.LETTER = a.LETTER
  FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 t2
    ON t2.LETTER = a.LETTER
```

which, if ALPHABET is only populated with ('A, 'B', 'C', and 'D'), produces

```
LETTER  VALUE    NUM
A       2        1
B       5        (null)
C       (null)   7
D       (null)   (null)
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f558b/4) (and note that in the fiddle I changed the variable name `NUMBER` to `NUM` to eliminate the need to double-quote it everywhere it's used).